# bash: using variables in the assosiative arrays

Tags: arrays, bash, list

In my bash script I have a list contained two elements

```
prot_list=( sars3CLpro 229e3CL )
```

and then several assosiative arrays that relate both of them to some other variables:

```
declare -A search_pattern1=(
    ["sars3CLpro"]="GLU 166 N"
    ["229e3CL"]="GLU 165 N"
)

declare -A search_pattern2=(
    ["sars3CLpro"]="HIE 163"
    ["229e3CL"]="HIE 162"
```

)

How would it be possible to use in the assosiative arrays the elements from the first list (like prot_list[0], prot_list[1]) thus avoiding to indicate "sars3CLpro" and "229e3CL" second time in the same script?

Comment: `["${prot_list[0]}"]="GLU 166 N"` etc

Comment: ${prot_list[0]} refers to the first element in the prot_list ? So the numbering is like python, starting from zero ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array index syntax even inside the associative array index:

```bash
declare -A search_pattern2=(
    ["${prot_list[0]}"]="HIE 163"
    ["${prot_list[1]}"]="HIE 162"
)
```

Arrays in bash are indexed starting from 0 as `man bash` tells us:

> Indexed arrays are referenced using integers (including  arithmetic  expressions)  and are zero-based

Or you can populate the associative arrays in loops:

```bash
declare -A search_pattern1
values1=('GLU 166 N' 'GLU 165 N')
for i in 0 1 ; do
    search_pattern1["${prot_list[i]}"]=${values1[i]}
done

declare -A search_pattern2
values2=('HIE 163' 'HIE 162')
for i in 0 1 ; do
    search_pattern2["${prot_list[i]}"]=${values2[i]}
done
```

Unfortunately, bash lacks the syntax to assign a list of values to a list of keys, unlike Perl, where you can do

```perl
    @search_pattern1{@prot_list} = @values1;
```

Comment: ${prot_list[0]} refers to the first element in the prot_list (sars3CLpro) ? So the numbering is like python, starting from zero ??

Comment: also possible to access later: `${search_pattern1[${prot_list[0]}]}`, etc

Comment: great explication! thank you so much! Cheers

Comment: justo ne question is it possible in bash to assign both variables (search_pattern1 and search_pattern2) in a single declare -A command?

Comment: Yes, as `man bash` and `help declare` tell you, you can use `declare -A a1=([x]=b) a2=([y]=c) ...`.